# Lisp: labels or separate global functions?

Tags: common-lisp

This is what my `wason-deck` produces:

```
((15 . D) (35 . H) (3 . B) (19 . K) (L . 15) (A . 16) (T . 23) (R . 53)
 (N . 13) (M . 7) (I . 52) (35 . Q) (S . 19) (Y . 29) (45 . G) (44 . W)
 (11 . V) (J . 25) (21 . F) (39 . Z) (25 . X) (50 . E) (5 . P) (33 . C)
 (O . 34))
```

this being a list of pairs representing a *Wason deck*. (See [this](http://www.math.niu.edu/~richard/Math101/implies.pdf), Example 6). In the deck there should be all the letters of the alphabet matched with even or odd numbers depending on whether a vowel or consonant respectively. I randomly shuffle and flip the cards as you can see. Then I (optionally) randomly *pollute* the deck by occasionally breaking the vowel:even, consonant:odd rule. Here's the code I've come up with:

```
(defun wason-deck (&optional (p 0))
  "This `consolst` and `vowlist` building is unnecessary, but a good exercise"
  (let* ((alphab '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z))
         (consonents '(b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z))
         (consolst (remove 'NIL (mapcar (lambda (x) (find x consonents)) alphab)))
         (vowlst (remove 'NIL (mapcar (lambda (x) (find x '(a e i o))) alphab)))
         (wdeck '()))

    (labels ((make-consodeck ()
               (mapcar (lambda (x) (let ((num (random 54)))
                                     (cons x (if (evenp num)
                                                 (1+ num)
                                                 num)))) consolst))
             (make-voweldeck () 
               (mapcar (lambda (x) (let ((num (random 54)))
                                     (cons x (if (oddp num)
                                                 (1+ num)
                                                 num)))) vowlst))
             (swap (slst el1 el2)
               (let  ((tmp (elt slst el1)))
                 (setf (elt slst el1) (elt slst el2))
                 (setf (elt slst el2) tmp)))

             (shuffle (slst)
               (loop for i in (reverse (range (length slst) :min 1))
                  do (let ((j (random (+ i 1))))
                       (swap slst i j)))
               slst)
             (flip (flst)
               (mapcar (lambda (x) (let ((num (random 2)))
                                     (if (zerop num)
                                         (cons (cdr x) (car x))
                                         x))) flst)))
      (setf wdeck (flip (shuffle (append (make-consodeck) (make-voweldeck)))))

      (if (zerop p) wdeck
          (mapcar (lambda (x) (let ((num (random 6)))
                                (cond ((and (zerop num) (numberp (car x))) (cons (1+ (car x)) (cdr x)))
                                      ((and (zerop num) (numberp (cdr x))) (cons (car x) (1+ (cdr x))))
                                      (t x)))) wdeck)))))
```

It works, but what I fear is not really knowing what I'm doing, i.e., I've misused `labels` as well as done a `setf` in the code. If some of the more senior people could tell me whether this is totally off in the wrong direction or not.

Addendum:

This is what I've got after the suggestions from below:

```
(defun wason-deck3 (&optional (p 0))
  (let* ((consonents '(b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z))
         (vowels '(a e i o u))
         (conso-deck (mapcar (lambda (x)
                               (cons x (1+ (* 2 (random 27)))))
                             consonents))
         (vowel-deck (mapcar (lambda (x)
                               (cons x (* 2 (random 27))))
                             vowels))
         (wdeck '()))
    (labels
        ((shuffle (slst)
           (loop :for i :from (1- (length slst)) :downto 1
              :do (rotatef (nth i slst)
                           (nth (random (1+ i)) slst)))
                           slst)

         (flip (flst)
           (mapcar (lambda (x) (let ((num (random 2)))
                                 (if (zerop num)
                                     (cons (cdr x) (car x))
                                     x))) flst)))

      (setf wdeck (flip (shuffle (append conso-deck vowel-deck)))))

    (if (zerop p) wdeck
        (mapcar (lambda (x) (let ((num (random 6)))
                              (cond ((and (zerop num) (numberp (car x))) (cons (1+ (car x)) (cdr x)))
                                    ((and (zerop num) (numberp (cdr x))) (cons (car x) (1+ (cdr x))))
                                    (t x)))) wdeck))))
```

Please add any new suggestions.

Comment: That example says nothing about consonants always having an odd number on the back side.

Comment: You can replace some of your functions in the `labels` with a plain `let` for starters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `labels` is totally OK, and your code is not entirely unreasonable.

A few pointers:

- I'd represent characters as characters: `'(#\a #\b #\c …)`
- I'd take my list exercises elsewhere, or at least use `set-difference`.
- When you create a function for just one call, you might as well just save the result:

  ```
  (let ((consonant-deck (mapcar (lambda (c)
                                  (cons c (1+ (* 2 (random 27)))))
                                consonants))
        (vowel-deck (mapcar (lambda (c)
                              (cons c (* 2 (random 27))))
                            vowels)))
    …)
  ```
- For swapping, there is `rotatef`: `(rotatef (nth i list) (nth j list))`.  Such things are rather expensive on lists, so I'd prefer to use a vector for this.  Then it comes in handy that a string is just a vector of characters…
- `Loop` can do counting for you, you don't need to create lists:

  ```
  (loop :for i :from (1- (length list)) :downto 1
        :do (rotatef (nth i list)
                     (nth (random (1+ i)) list)))
  ```

  (Using keywords as loop keywords is optional, but indentation should be like this.)
- If you put the `labels` around the `let`, you can immediately bind `wdeck`, so that you do not need to `setf` it afterwards.
- You do not need this function for the exercise that you linked to.

Comment: Thanks, Svante, for your detailed help; I'll go through each point as time allows. As for your last point, I want to look at a whole deck, the exercise being just one possible test case. I asked over on the math.stackexchange why just four cards -- and no one seemed to know why. It seems like a combinatorics issue somehow. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the second to last bullet. How can the `labels` go around the `let*`?

Comment: I meant that the `labels` bindings do not depend on the `let*` bindings, so you can say `(labels ((shuffle …) (flip …)) (let ((consonants …) … (wdeck (flip (…))))))`.